# How to create a configuration file

Tags: android

I want to develop an application to use it as launcher with many user, in this launcher each person have his one applications. I wrote a filter that use to specify for each user what applications will use. But now i would like that the list of file will be configured using file that are not saved with the application path but in files that will be created in internal storage. So when i change the list in this file i change the list of application without compiling  apk. but i need that the internal file to write can be edited by other application.
But i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

for something like this you definitely would want to use a SQL database, read the storage options topic on the Android Developers website:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html